# Can a speaker be thought-provoking?

Tags: word-choice

Can a person be "thought-provoking"? Or is this term only properly applied to concepts and things such as articles, theories, concepts, questions?

The dictionary says thought-provoking means "causing people to think seriously about something." And, sure, people can certainly cause one to think seriously about something. But I think the term is meant to suggest a conceptual or intellectual element.

Comment: *She's a very thought-provoking speaker* is fine for me, but I think the kind of thing you have in mind is more like *he's a thought-provoking person* - which is OK IMO, although *he's the sort of person who makes you think* sounds better.

Answer (score 1):

**thought-provoking** adj. [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/201055?redirectedFrom=thought%20provoking#eid18615061)

> prompting serious thought.

As in:

*The speaker at tonight's event was very **thought-provoking***

and good use of the adjective.